# Fast methods for approximating the highest 3 eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a large symmetric matrix

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, matrix, eigenvalue

I am writing code to compute [Classical Multidimensional Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling#Classical_multidimensional_scaling) (abbreviated to MDS) of a very large `n` by `n` matrix, `n = 500,000` in my example.

In one step of MDS, I need to compute the highest three [eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of a `n` by `n` matrix.  This matrix is called the `B` matrix.  I only need these three eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  Common methods of calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a large matrix take a long time, and I do not require a very accurate answer, so I am seeking an estimation of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Some parameters:

1. The `B` matrix is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), [real](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealMatrix.html), and quite [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)
2. The eigenvalue decomposition of `B` in theory should always produce real numbers.
3. I do not require an entirely precise estimation, just a fast one.  I would need it to complete in several hours.
4. I write in python and C++

My question: Are there fast methods of estimating the three highest eigenvectors and eigenvalues of such a large `B` matrix?

My progress: I have found a [method of approximating the highest eigenvalue of a matrix](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/5e/students/ch08-10/chap_10_3.pdf), but I do not know if I can generalize it to the highest three.  I have also found [this paper written in 1996](http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/96-043.pdf), but it is extremely technical and hard for me to read.

Comment: A matrix that size would require more than a terabyte of storage given 64-bit floating-point entries. Forget eigenvectors -- even doing a single matrix-vector multiplication looks painful.

Comment: But there is no need to store the original matrix! It is indirectly given in the MDS algorithm and you can use that to perform matrix-vector multiplication without first computing the matrix.

Comment: Have you looked at approximate MDS meant for big data?  E.g. see http://pike.cs.ucla.edu/~weiwang/paper/CIMCV06.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

G. Golub and C.F Van Loan Matrix Computations 2nd in chapter 9 state that Lanczos algorithms are one choice for this (except that the matrix should ideally be sparse - it clearly works for non-sparse ones as well)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

You can get the highest eigenvector of `B` and then, transform the data into `B'` using that eigenvector. Then pop the first column of `B'` and get `B''` so you can get the highest eigenvector of `B''`: it is enough information to compose a plausible second highest eigenvector for `B`. And then for the third.

About speed: you can randomly sample that huge dataset to be only a dataset of `N` items. If you are getting only three dimensions, I hope you can also get rid of most of the data to get an overview of the eigenvectors. You can call it: 'electoral poll'. I cannot help you in measuring the error rate, but I will try sampling 1k items, several times, and seeing if results are more or less the same.

Now you can get the mean of several 'polls' to build a 'prediction'.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at suggestions in this thread

[Largest eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468537/largest-eigenvalues-and-corresponding-eigenvectors-in-c?rq=1)

As suggested there you can use ARPACK package which has a C++ interface.